# Difference between self and private method call in R6

Tags: r, r6

Lately I found myself coding some stuff in R6, and while having fun handling some objects an interesting question came out. When creating a private method (e.g. foo, of the bar) and calling it inside other public methods it works if I either call it using:

```
self$foo
```

and

```
private$foo
```

What I am asking is: what is the difference between those two ways of calling a method in R6? 
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the "Introduction to R6 classes" vignette (emphasis mine):

`self`

> Inside methods of the class, `self` refers to the object. **Public** members of the object (all you’ve seen so far) are accessed with `self$x`

`private`

> Whereas public members are accessed with `self`, like `self$add()`, **private members** are accessed with `private`, like `private$queue`.

So, even if you *can* access private methods through `self`, you should do it through `private`. Don't rely on behavior which may go away, seeing as how the documentation says it shouldn't work like that.

That said, I can't access private methods using `self`:

```
library(R6)

bar <- R6Class("bar",
  private = list(
    foo = function() {
      message("just foo it")
    }
  ),
  public = list(
    call_self = function() {
      self$foo()
    },
    call_private = function() {
      private$foo()
    }
  )
)

b <- bar$new()
b$call_private()
# just foo it
b$call_self()
# Error in b$call_self() : attempt to apply non-function
```